# How can I combine sum, if and log to calculate this sum(-a1:a3*log(a1:a3,2))?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, entropy

I want to calculate the entropy (of a information source) from the distribution of probabilities of the column A:

```
    A
1: 0.75
2: 0.25
3: 0
```

the entropy h is equal to:

> h = -0.75*log2(0.75) -0.25*log2(0.25) = 0.812 (aprox)

I have tried things like this:

```
=SUM(-A1:A3*if(A1:A3<>0,log(A1:A3,2)))
```

but it does not work, I got the error "an array value could not be found"

This is my first time using google sheets, sorry if i'm not clear.

Comment: try: `=SUMPRODUCT(-A1:A3*IF(A1:A3<>0,LOG(A1:A3,2),A1:A3))`

Comment: it's perfect, it seems that I wasn't far from the right answer!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this formula instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(-A1:A3*IF(A1:A3<>0,LOG(A1:A3,2),A1:A3))
```